# Python syntax clarification

Tags: python

Scrolling through the python 2.7 docs I came across this snippet

```
def fib(n):    # write Fibonacci series up to n
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:
        print a,
        a, b = b, a+b
```

But I don't understand the last line, and unsure of how I would google for it.

How should I read `a, b = b, a+b`, or, what does it mean ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python evaluates the right-hand side of assignments first. It evaluates

```
b, a+b
```

from left to right. It then assigns the values to the variables `a` and `b` respectively.

So `a, b = b, a+b` is equivalent to

```
c = b
d = a+b
a = c
b = d
```

except that it achieves the result without explicit temporary variables.
See the docs on Python's [evaluation order](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order).

---

There is a subtle point here worth examining with an example. Suppose a = 1, b = 2.

```
a, b = b, a+b
```

is equivalent to

```
a, b = 2, 1+2 
a, b = 2, 3
```

So `a` gets assign to 2, `b` is assigned to 3.

Notice that this is **not** equivalent to

```
a = b
b = a + b
```

Since the first line would assign

```
a = 2
b = 2 + 2 = 4
```

Notice that done this (wrong) way, `b` ends up equal to 4, not 3. That's why it is important to know that Python evaluates the right-hand side of assignments first (before any assignments are made).

Comment: @njzk2 Not in this case, but there may be cases where it would be, using this sort of assignment.

Comment: @njzk2: If you assign `a = b` first, then you've lost the original value of `a`. So `a+b` will be (in general) incorrect. Thus, you need a temporary variable `c`. I would agree that `d` is not strictly needed however.

Comment: @both : that's right, in fact, c (and d) can be useful in the general case.

Comment: And I assume the order is important, so that `a, b = b, a+b` would be something like `a = b` `b = a + b` ?

Comment: No. Everything happens at the same time.

Comment: @user1021726: No, see above for why that is not what Python is doing.

Answer (score 4):

It is setting a to b, and b to a + b, without needing an intermediate variable. It could also be accomplished with:

```
temp = a
a = b
b = temp + b
```

Comment: Very good answer. The only reason you didn't get the voted answer is because I felt the comments and edit on the other answer provided a bit more information, but your answer definitely helped! :)